# The method 'save' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: save()

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to set value of form field to 'username' variable when we tap on gestureDetector.
And the text within 'username' variable is passing back to function createUserInFirestore() from create_account.dart to home.dart using Navigator.pop() method

I am also attaching the code for reference

This is my create_account.dart file

```
class CreateAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateAccountState createState() => _CreateAccountState();
}

class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey =GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username="";

  submit(){
    _formkey.currentState.save();
    Navigator.pop(context,username);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context,titleText: "Set up your profile"),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child:Column(
              children:<Widget> [
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Create a username", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),),
                ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Container(
                  child:Form(
                    key: _formkey,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onSaved: (val)=>username=val,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Username",
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                        hintText: "Must be at leat 3 characterstics",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: submit(),
                  child: Container(
                    height:50.0 ,
                    width: 350.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child:Text(
                      "Submit", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                    ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ) ,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And home.dart file

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIN = GoogleSignIn();
final DateTime timestamp= DateTime.now();
final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isAuth=false;
  PageController pageController;
  int pageIndex=0;


  createUserInFirestore() async{
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIN.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.doc(user.id).get();
    if(!doc.exists){
      final username = await Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: context)=>CreateAccount()));

      userRef.doc(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "username":username,
        "photoUrl":user.photoUrl,
        "email":user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio":"",
        "timestamp":timestamp
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    pageController= PageController();
    googleSignIN.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    },onError: (err){
      print('Enter signing in: $err');
    });


    googleSignIN.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false)
      .then((account){
        handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err){
      print('Enter signing in: $err');
    });
  }

  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account){
    if(account!=null){
      createUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth=true;
      });
    }else{
      setState(() {
        isAuth=false;
      });
    }
  }



  @override
  void dispose(){
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  login(){
    googleSignIN.signIn();
  }

  logout(){
    googleSignIN.signOut();
  }

  onPageChanged(int pageIndex){
    setState(() {
      this.pageIndex=pageIndex;
    });
  }

  onTap(int pageIndex){
    pageController.animateToPage(
      pageIndex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInCirc
    );
  }
  Scaffold buildAuthScreen(){
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Logout'),
          onPressed: logout,
          ),
        ActivityFeed(),
        Upload(),
        Search(),
        Profile(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: onTap,
        activeColor:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot),),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera,size: 35.0,),),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search),),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildUnAuthScreen(){
    return Scaffold(
      body:Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ]
          ),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('LS App',
            style: GoogleFonts.dellaRespira(fontSize: 50.0)
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: login,
              child: Container(
                width: 260.0,
                height: 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image:DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/google_signin_button.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth?buildAuthScreen():buildUnAuthScreen();
  }
}
```

Also the log

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CreateAccount(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#f10cd], _InheritedTheme], state: _CreateAccountState#4c9d8):
The method 'save' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: save()

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CreateAccount file:///C:/Users/reddy/AndroidStudioProjects/ls_app/lib/pages/home.dart:36:91
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _CreateAccountState.submit (package:ls_app/pages/create_account.dart:16:27)
#2      _CreateAccountState.build (package:ls_app/pages/create_account.dart:52:26)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
...
```

This error message is what I get and if you need more code please let me know,
Thanks for the help..!

Comment: use `onTap: submit` without paranthesis

Comment: check the duplicate to understand why it works